# Are these the integration techniques recommended for this exercise?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I did this exercise but I'm not sure if is done correctly. I tried to check it in Symbolab or Mathway, but didn't provide an answer. I will appreciate anyone reviewing my work and checking if is right or wrong. If it is wrong I would like to know the best way to do it. Thanks.

$$\int e^{-\sqrt[3]{t}}\;\mathrm{d}t$$

I'm doing it by substitution. I'm choosing $w=-\sqrt[3]{t}=-t^{\frac{1}{3}}$

$$w=-t^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$-w=t^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$(-w)^{3}=(t^{\frac{1}{3}})^{3}$$ 
$$-w^{3}=t$$

Then,

$$dw=-\frac{1}{3}t^{-\frac{2}{3}}dt$$
$$dw=-\frac{1}{3t^{\frac{2}{3}}}dt$$
$$(-3t^{\frac{2}{3}})dw=-\frac{1}{3t^{\frac{2}{3}}}dt(-3t^{\frac{2}{3}})$$
$$-3t^{\frac{2}{3}}dw=dt$$
$$-3(-w^{3})^{\frac{2}{3}}dw=dt$$
$$-3(-w)^{2}dw=dt$$
$$-3w^{2}dw=dt$$

So the integral follows,

$$\int e^{-\sqrt[3]{t}}\;\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\int e^{w}\cdot-3w^{2}\;\mathrm{d}w$$
$$=-3\int e^{w}w^{2}\;\mathrm{d}w$$

Now, I'm doing integration by parts,

Let $u=w^2\Rightarrow du=2wdw$

Let $dv=e^{w}dw\Rightarrow v=e^{w}$

$$-3\int e^{w}w^{2}\;\mathrm{d}w$$
$$=-3[w^{2}e^{w}-\int e^{w}\cdot2w\;\mathrm{d}w]$$
$$=-3[w^{2}e^{w}-2\int e^{w}w\;\mathrm{d}w]$$
$$=-3w^{2}e^{w}+6\int e^{w}w\;\mathrm{d}w$$

Now, integration by parts again,

Let $u=w\Rightarrow du=dw$

Let $dv=e^{w}dw\Rightarrow v=e^{w}$

$$=-3w^{2}e^{w}+6\int e^{w}w\;\mathrm{d}w$$
$$=-3w^{2}e^{w}+6[we^{w}-\int e^{w}\;\mathrm{d}w]$$
$$=-3w^{2}e^{w}+6we^{w}-6\int e^{w}\;\mathrm{d}w$$
$$=-3w^{2}e^{w}+6we^{w}-6e^{w}+C$$

Remember, I choose $w=-t^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Then,

$$=-3w^{2}e^{w}+6we^{w}-6e^{w}+C$$
$$=-3e^{w}[w^{2}-2w+2]+C$$
$$=-3e^{-t^{\frac{1}{3}}}[(-t^{\frac{1}{3}})^{2}-2(-t^{\frac{1}{3}})+2]+C$$
$$=-3e^{-t^{\frac{1}{3}}}[(-1t^{\frac{1}{3}})^{2}+2t^{\frac{1}{3}}+2]+C$$
$$=-3e^{-t^{\frac{1}{3}}}[(-1)^2(t^{\frac{1}{3}})^{2}+2t^{\frac{1}{3}}+2]+C$$
$$=-3e^{-t^{\frac{1}{3}}}[1t^{\frac{2}{3}}+2t^{\frac{1}{3}}+2]+C$$
$$=-3e^{-t^{\frac{1}{3}}}[t^{\frac{2}{3}}+2t^{\frac{1}{3}}+2]+C$$
$$=-3e^{-\sqrt[3]{t}}[\sqrt[3]{t^2}+2\sqrt[3]{t}+2]+C$$

Comment: The technique is correct. The calculations look correct to me.

Comment: Nice work and perfect result and $\to +1$. You could do it a bit faster using $t=-w ^3$ then $dt=-3w^2\,dw$.

Comment: Awesome thank you both! <3

@ClaudeLeibovici hah!!! yes... definitely much faster.

Comment: Here's a working link to Symbolab for this problem: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cint%20e%5E%7Bt%5E%7B-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%7D%7D%7D
(I work at Symbolab)